# URL Encoding Error

Tags: url, apache-camel, jql

I'm invoking a URL from Apache Camel.

I'm Setting the headers "Exchange.HTTP_URI" as 
    `http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=Name~ABC`

But it gives error saying 
Invoking 
    `http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search?jql=Name<b>%257E`ABC

Why is **~** being converted into **%257E**
%7E  is the code for ~
and %25 is code for %

When i set the headers "Exchange.HTTP_QUERY" , it runs but when i saw,
it actually runs only `http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/search` and returns the response.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet works perfectly well:

```
public class HttpQueryTest 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("http://google.com?q=Name~ABC"))
                        .to("http://localhost/noSuchUrl").to("log:OUT");
            }
        });
        camelContext.start();
        camelContext.createProducerTemplate().sendBody("direct:start","start");

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
}
```

As I can see in log:

```
12:59:11.230 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.component.http.HttpProducer - Executing http GET method: http://google.com?q=Name~ABC
12:59:11.650 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.component.http.HttpProducer - Http responseCode: 200
```

As you can see it sets the destination URL using the Exchange.HTTP_URI header value. Then it creates Google query with parameters similar to yours.

Could you provide the snippet that demonstrates your problem so I could reproduce it?